# Parsing an ISO file with Hachoir

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, iso

I'm trying to parse and extract an ISO file using [Hachoir](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/). However, the documentation is not very clear, it specifies that ISO is a supported parser, but I can't seem to find any example, information, or help on how to parse it.

What I've figured out so far:

```
from hachoir_core.cmd_line import unicodeFilename
from hachoir_parser import createParser

filepath = "dsl-4.11.rcl.iso"
filename, realfilename = unicodeFilename(filepath), filepath
parser = createParser(filename)
for s in parser:
    print s,address, s.name, s,size
```

This will output something along the lines of:

```
0 padding[0] 262144
262144 Volume[0] 16384
... etc
```

So my question being, does anyone know where there is any form of documentation of this, besides the wiki (because it isn't very clear and gives no examples), or how I can extract the ISO file with hachoir?

Comment: I have no experience of this. If you can't find documentation for Hachoir, you might find useful alternatives by searching for Python parsers for ISO 9660.

Comment: @BillBell I've done that, they all seem to do the same thing, and none of them seem to be able to actually extract the ISO. I've figured out about three different parsers so far, it seems like until I can figure out how to get them to extract, my best best is to just use the `isinfo` command